# Python- Encoding two letters

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a python playfair cipher and am encountering a few problems along the way. I have a five by five table with the following information:

```
 [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
 ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
 ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]
```

I am supposed to encrypt two letters at a time. When given the input encrypt (B, N), the resulting output should be DL. The first letter in the input should return the letter in the same row as B, but that has the column N. I was hoping someone could explain a way for me to accomplish that.

With some assistance from the friendly users here, this is what some of the code looks like:

```
def find_index(letter, table):
    for i,li in enumerate(table):
        try:
            j=li.index(letter)
            return i,j
        except ValueError:
            pass    

    raise ValueError("'{}' not in matrix".format(letter))
print "Row:Column"
print find_index('I', table)  


def encode(a, b):
    if a == b:
        print "ERROR: letters to encode_pair must be distinct"
    print find_index (a,table)
    print find_index (b, table)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get ASCII value of char using ord() in python.

of EX

s='A'

change_s=chr(ord(s)+2)

so resulting out put comes change_s = 'C'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
In [25]: table = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
 ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
 ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]

In [26]: def encrypt(B, N):
    b = [L.index(B) for L in table if B in L][0]
    answer = [L for L in table if N in L][0][b]
    b = [L.index(N) for L in table if N in L][0]
    answer = answer,[L for L in table if B in L][0][b]
    return answer

In [27]: encrypt("B", "N")
Out[27]: ('L', 'D')
```

Comment: I think he needs D also -- the other corner of the square.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the returns from find_index (a,table) and find_index (a,table) and if I understand correctly this is the kind of code you will need to implement

```
def encode(a, b):
    if a == b:
        print "ERROR: letters to encode_pair must be distinct"
    print find_index (a,table)
    print find_index (b, table) 
    index_a= find_index (a,table)
    index_b = find_index (a,table)
    new_a_index = [index_a[0], index_b[1]]
    new_b_index = [index_b[0], index_a[1]]
    new_a = table[new_a_index]
    new_b = table[new_b_index]
```

The last steps could be done in one step, but I was trying to be clear to ensure you understood what I was doing and to correct me if I misunderstood

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding promptly, but I seem to be having some trouble. When I attempt to run the code, I receive the following error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list" Is there any way to solve that.

Comment: I see the problem that I created. I wasn't thinking in strict code.

you will want each of the last four lines in only two lines to make this simpler 
`code new_a = table[index_b[0]][index_a[1]]` 
`new_b = table[index_a[0]][index_b[1]]`

I might have gotten the row/columns mixed up so you might need to reorder that, but that should solve the typeError which was occuring because new_a and new_b were being fed lists of the indexes rather than two indexes

Comment: Thank you again for responding but I still can not seem to make it work properly. Maybe I did a poor job of explaining the task. This is how the program is suppost to function: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quKhvu2tPy8 from 1:00 onwards, the rules are explained. I was attempting to use the idea you came up with to create the rest of the rules, but I was unable to do so. If you're able to help me further, that would be amazing, but I understand if you do no. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: I just ran it, it works. I think you might be having an input issue, are you getting this error?
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: `

Comment: `new_a = tablez[index_b[0]][index_a[1]]  
new_b = tablez[index_a[0]][index_b[1]] `

is actually correct. 

I am guessing the issue you are having is that you are trying to pass a variable called A rather than passing the string 'A'

Answer (score 0):

That was fun... thanks.

```
In [2]:



class Encoder(object):
    m = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
     ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
     ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
     ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]    

    def encode(self, first, second):
        first_row_idx, first_col_idx = self.get_rowcol(first)
        second_row_idx, second_col_idx = self.get_rowcol(second)        
        encoded_first = self.m[first_row_idx][second_col_idx]
        encoded_second = self.m[second_row_idx][first_col_idx]
        return encoded_first, encoded_second

    def get_rowcol(self, letter):
        letter = letter.upper()
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(self.m):
            for col_idx, col_letter in enumerate(row):
                if col_letter == letter:
                    return row_idx, col_idx
        raise ValueError("({}) not found in matrix!".format(letter))


e = Encoder()
e.encode("B", "N")

Out[2]:
('D', 'L')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> cl=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
 ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
 ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]
>>> M = list(chain(*cl))
>>> N = len(cl[0])
>>> def e(a, b):
        ia,ib = M.index(a), M.index(b)
        ar,ac = ia / N, ia % N
        br,bc = ib / N, ib % N
        return M[ar*N + bc], M[br*N + ac]

>>> e('B','N')
# ('D', 'L')
```